# PXE boot fails with PXE-99: "Unexpected network error"

Tags: dhcp, pxe, isc-kea, intel-boot-agent

I've configured a Kea DHCP server as follows (two different interfaces serving two different networks):

```json
{
    "Dhcp4": {
        "valid-lifetime": 4000,
        "renew-timer": 1000,
        "rebind-timer": 2000,
        "interfaces-config": {
            "interfaces": [ "eth0", "eth1" ]
        },
        "lease-database": {
            "type": "memfile",
            "persist": true,
            "name": "/var/lib/kea/kea-leases4.csv"
        },
        "subnet4": [
            {
                "subnet": "192.168.8.0/24",
                "pools": [
                    {
                         "pool": "192.168.8.2 - 192.168.8.200"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "subnet": "192.168.9.0/24",
                "pools": [
                    {
                         "pool": "192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.200"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "option-data": [
            {
                "name": "domain-name-servers",
                "data": "1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8"
            },
            {
                "name": "routers",
                "data": "192.168.8.1,192.168.9.1"
            }
        ],
        "client-classes":
        [
            {
                "name": "UEFI-32",
                "test": "substring(option[60].hex,0,20) == 'PXEClient:Arch:00006'",
                "boot-file-name": "ipxe/i386.efi"
            },
            {
                "name": "UEFI-64",
                "test": "substring(option[60].hex,0,20) == 'PXEClient:Arch:00007'",
                "boot-file-name": "ipxe/x86_64.efi"
            },
      ]
   }
}
```

When I do `tcpdump -i eth0 -nn -vvvv`, I do see the DHCP request/response:

```
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 74:56:3c:83:a0:85, length 359, xid 0xb9760545, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
      Client-Ethernet-Address 74:56:3c:83:a0:85
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Request
        Server-ID (54), length 4: 192.168.8.1
        Requested-IP (50), length 4: 192.168.8.2
        MSZ (57), length 2: 65280
        Parameter-Request (55), length 35: 
          Subnet-Mask (1), Time-Zone (2), Default-Gateway (3), Time-Server (4)
          IEN-Name-Server (5), Domain-Name-Server (6), Hostname (12), BS (13)
          Domain-Name (15), RP (17), EP (18), RSZ (22)
          TTL (23), BR (28), YD (40), YS (41)
          NTP (42), Vendor-Option (43), Requested-IP (50), Lease-Time (51)
          Server-ID (54), RN (58), RB (59), Vendor-Class (60)
          TFTP (66), BF (67), GUID (97), Unknown (128)
          Unknown (129), Unknown (130), Unknown (131), Unknown (132)
          Unknown (133), Unknown (134), Unknown (135)
        GUID (97), length 17: 0.0.192.165.218.38.183.238.17.128.0.116.86.60.131.160.133
        NDI (94), length 3: 1.3.16
        ARCH (93), length 2: 7
        Vendor-Class (60), length 32: "PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003016"
        END (255), length 0
22:54:47.774286 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 318)
    192.168.8.1.67 > 255.255.255.255.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 290, xid 0xb9760545, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
      Your-IP 192.168.8.2
      Client-Ethernet-Address 74:56:3c:83:a0:85
      file "ipxe/x86_64.efi"
      Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
        Magic Cookie 0x63825363
        DHCP-Message (53), length 1: ACK
        Subnet-Mask (1), length 4: 255.255.255.0
        Default-Gateway (3), length 4: 192.168.9.1
        Domain-Name-Server (6), length 8: 1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
        Lease-Time (51), length 4: 4000
        Server-ID (54), length 4: 192.168.8.1
        RN (58), length 4: 1000
        RB (59), length 4: 2000
        END (255), length 0
```

but I don't see any tftp requests at all. On the screen I see (very briefly):

```
Station IP address is 192.168.8.2
Server IP address is 192.168.8.1
NBP filename is ipxe/x86_64.efi
NBP filesize 0 Bytes
PXE-E99: Unexpected network error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few behaviors that are interacting here to cause the problem:

1. The Kea DHCP server does not use the assigned subnet to figure out what router to serve. As you can see in the tcpdump, it gave out the `192.168.9.1` router to the `192.168.8.0/24` subnet. To fix this, you can provide separate "option-data" specifications in each of your subnets:

   ```json
   "subnet4": [
       {
           "subnet": "192.168.8.0/24",
           "pools": [
               {
                    "pool": "192.168.8.2 - 192.168.8.200"
               }
           ],
           "option-data": [
               {
                   "name": "routers",
                   "data": "192.168.8.1"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "subnet": "192.168.9.0/24",
           "pools": [
               {
                    "pool": "192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.200"
               }
           ],
           "option-data": [
               {
                   "name": "routers",
                   "data": "192.168.9.1"
               }
           ]
       },
   ]
   ```
2. The reason you might not see a problem with this configuration outside the pxe context is that ordinarily, the router is not required to reach a host within the same subnet as the client will add a route for the /24 subnet based on the netmask. However, the PXE networking stack does not do this and always uses the default route, so adding it to the configuration is required.